# How to get last second of every minute from mongoDB using SQL query

Tags: sql, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, seconds

I have a table with records for every millisecond. I need to get only the last second of every minute using Mongodb sql query.

```
Id   Balance             DataTime

1  "2462188.61"  2019-09-27T05:49:33.575+00:00

1  "2449426.30"  2019-10-30T19:30:52.513+00:00

1  "2456459.67"  2019-10-15T18:20:09.490+00:00

5  "1006266.91"  2019-10-31T13:48:18.290+00:00
```

I tried the LIKE condition but that didn't work.
`Select Id, DateTime,Balance from AccountBalance where DateTime like '%59.000%'`

Here is the link for the mongoldb SQL reference : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/supported-operations/

I am using the BI connector to connect to Tableau(hence need the sql version of the query)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a sql question or mongodb?

Comment: I am querying Mongodb using SQL

Comment: Are you using some GUI/IDE like studio3t or noSQLBooster which basically converts these sql queries to mongo ones (which ofcouse will have limitations for complex queries)? And why not simply use mongo query as one of the answer posted.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example MongoDB document and information on the SQL connector version and MongoDB server version you are using. Assuming your `DateTime` field is a BSON Date type, matching using string operators such as `like` (which presumably translates into a regular expression in MongoDB Query Language) won't work. However, depending on your connector & server versions there may be available SQL date & time functions to extract the relevant values. It also looks like your current example data wouldn't match the intended query of "last second of each minute".

Comment: Thanks for the response @ambianBeing & @ Stennie. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
db.z.aggregate([
  {  $addFields:  {
    year: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y", date: "$DataTime" } },
    month: { $dateToString: { format: "%m", date: "$DataTime" } },
    day: { $dateToString: { format: "%d", date: "$DataTime" } },
    hour: { $dateToString: { format: "%H", date: "$DataTime" } },
    minute: { $dateToString: { format: "%M", date: "$DataTime" } },
    second: { $dateToString: { format: "%S", date: "$DataTime" } }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

This assumes your field DataTime is of type ISODate()...

**Example Documents:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dea94c3b4ae6bbc17cd023b"), "Balance" : "2462188.61", "DataTime" : ISODate("2019-09-27T05:49:33.575Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dea94c3b4ae6bbc17cd023c"), "Balance" : "2449426.30", "DataTime" : ISODate("2019-10-30T19:30:52.513Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dea94c3b4ae6bbc17cd023d"), "Balance" : "2456459.67", "DataTime" : ISODate("2019-10-15T18:20:09.490Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dea94c3b4ae6bbc17cd023e"), "Balance" : "1006266.91", "DataTime" : ISODate("2019-10-31T13:48:18.290Z") }
```

**Example Query Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dea94c3b4ae6bbc17cd023b"),
    "Balance" : "2462188.61",
    "DataTime" : ISODate("2019-09-27T05:49:33.575Z"),
    "year" : "2019",
    "month" : "09",
    "day" : "27",
    "hour" : "05",
    "minute" : "49",
    "second" : "33"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dea94c3b4ae6bbc17cd023c"),
    "Balance" : "2449426.30",
    "DataTime" : ISODate("2019-10-30T19:30:52.513Z"),
    "year" : "2019",
    "month" : "10",
    "day" : "30",
    "hour" : "19",
    "minute" : "30",
    "second" : "52"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dea94c3b4ae6bbc17cd023d"),
    "Balance" : "2456459.67",
    "DataTime" : ISODate("2019-10-15T18:20:09.490Z"),
    "year" : "2019",
    "month" : "10",
    "day" : "15",
    "hour" : "18",
    "minute" : "20",
    "second" : "09"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dea94c3b4ae6bbc17cd023e"),
    "Balance" : "1006266.91",
    "DataTime" : ISODate("2019-10-31T13:48:18.290Z"),
    "year" : "2019",
    "month" : "10",
    "day" : "31",
    "hour" : "13",
    "minute" : "48",
    "second" : "18"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @barrypicker . But I am writing SQL to query Mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

use sort function with date

eg:

```
db.collection.find().sort("Date_Field")
```

Comment: Op is asking for SQL query which would query mongoDB !!